# Cancelling Akka scheduler

Tags: scala, akka, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Just wanted to know what's the best way to cancel a schedule.

At the moment I use a `var` linked to the scheduler task, and cancel it like so:

```
private var scheduterLink: akka.actor.Cancellable = null

def receive = {
    case Test => {
       if(...){scheduterLink.cancel}    
}
```

Any more examples how to do it without **var** links?

Thanks!

Comment: having a state in an actor is not too bad, you should avoid it as much as possible but accept when required. But there is a more important problem in your code, `null`.
What about using `private var scheduterLink: Option[Cancellable] = None`

Comment: thanks, I thought about Option. But thought akka has more convenient approach. Thank you.

Comment: Use `context.become` for 'pure' behaviour. Function must accept scheduler as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer solution on immutable you can change state of Actor like this:

```scala
  def receive: Receive = withoutCancel

  def withoutCancel:Receive = {
    case x =>
      if(???){
        context.become(withCancel(context.system.scheduler.schedule(....)))
      }
    ???
  }

  def withCancel(cancellable:Cancellable):Receive = {
    case Test =>
      if(???){
        cancellable.cancel()
        context.unbecome()
      }          
     ???
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
ActorRef tickActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(Ticker.class, this));

//This will schedule to send the Tick-message
//to the tickActor after 0ms repeating every 50ms
Cancellable cancellable = system.scheduler().schedule(Duration.Zero(),
Duration.create(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), tickActor, "Tick",
system.dispatcher(), null);

//This cancels further Ticks to be sent
cancellable.cancel();
```

Get it from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html